# In RedHat Linux, what do you use to calibrate a touch screen?

Tags: rhel, touch-screen

Years ago I had a Palm Pilot, and its touch screen required that you first calibrate it before using it.  To calibrate it, in the settings a program would be started, and you would click with your stylus in the center of a target at several places on the screen and it would end up clicking where you placed your stylus.

Do old Linux PC touch screens work in a similar manner to calibrate them?  If so, what command do I need to run in RedHat Linux to calibrate the touch screen?

Comment: I didn't know there _were_ old Linux touch screens... Are you having issues with a screen that appears uncalibrated? What is the hardware and what RedHat Linux release are you running?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's an old IBM 4800 POS I think...I don't know what version of RHL...

Comment: Point of Sale systems had this.

Comment: Likely SUSE - https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=AN&subtype=CA&htmlfid=649/ENUSA05-0659.